an estimate $\|\partial_v w\|_{H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega')}\leq C\|w\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$
$\partial_v w$ is conormal derivative of $w$.
Suppose that $\Omega$ is a Lipschitz domain and let $\Omega'$ be a compact subset of a $\Omega$.
Let $w:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a solution for a problem         \begin{equation*}
        L^*w = \begin{cases}
        h &\text{in } \Omega'\\
        0 &\text{in } \Omega\backslash \overline{\Omega'}
        \end{cases},
    \end{equation*} $w = 0$ on $\partial\Omega$, where $L$ is an elliptic operator and $h \in H^1(\Omega')$ is a solution to a problem $Lh = 0$ in $\Omega'$.
Do we have an estimate $\|\partial_v w\|_{H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega')} \leq C\|w\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$?
By the Green's identity we have
$\Phi(w,Eg) = (Eg, L^*w)_{L^2(\Omega)} - (g , \partial_v w)_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}$, where $E:H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega) \rightarrow H^1(\Omega)$ is an bounded extension operator. It follows that
$|(g , \partial_v w)_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}| \leq C\|g\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)}\|h\|_{L^2(\Omega')} + C\|g\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)}\|w\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$, dividing by $\|g\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)}$ by together taking the supremum yields us $\|\partial_v w\|_{H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega)}\leq C(\|h\|_{L^2(\Omega')} + \|w\|_{H^1(\Omega)})$. I think using the assumption that $L^*w=h$ might give us an estimate $\|h\|_{L^2(\Omega')} \leq C\|w\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$, which then would imply the the inequality.
For example something like $\|h\|_{L^2(\Omega')} = \|L^*w\|_{L^2(\Omega')} = \|-\nabla\cdot A\nabla w +b\cdot\nabla w + cw\|_{L^2(\Omega')} \leq \|-\nabla\cdot A\nabla w\|_{L^2(\Omega')} +\|b\cdot\nabla w\|_{L^2(\Omega')} + \|cw\|_{L^2(\Omega')} \leq \|-\nabla\cdot A\nabla w\|_{L^2(\Omega')} +C\|w\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$, but not sure yet how to estimate the term $\|-\nabla\cdot A\nabla w\|_{L^2(\Omega')}$, since there is 2nd derivatives included.
